# Sort across rows to obtain three largest values

Tags: r

There is a injury score called [ISS score](http://www.trauma.org/archive/scores/iss.html)

I have a table of injury data in rows according to pt ID.

I would like to obtain the top three values for the 6 injury columns.

Column values range from 0-5.

```
pt_id head face abdo pelvis Extremity External
1    4    0    0    1    0    3
2    3    3    5    0    3    2
3    0    0    2    1    1    1
4    2    0    0    0    0    1
5    5    0    0    2    0    1
```

My output for the above example would be

```
pt-id n1 n2 n3
1    4    3    1
2    5    3    3
3    2    1    1
4    2    1    0
5    5    2    1
```

values can be in a list or in new columns as calculating the score is simple from that point on.

I had thought that I would be able to create a list for the 6 injury columns and then apply a sort to each list taking the top three values. My code for that was:

```
ais$ais_list <- setNames(split(ais[,2:7], seq(nrow(ais))), rownames(ais))
```

But I struggled to apply the sort to the lists within the data frame as unfortunately some of the data in my data set includes NA values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `apply` row-wise and `sort` the dataframe and take only first three values in each row.

```
cbind(df[1], t(apply(df[-1], 1, sort, decreasing = TRUE)[1:3, ]))

#  pt_id 1 2 3
#1     1 4 3 1
#2     2 5 3 3
#3     3 2 1 1
#4     4 2 1 0
#5     5 5 2 1
```

As some values may contain `NA` it is better we `apply` `sort` using anonymous function and then take take top 3 values using `head`.

```
cbind(df[1], t(apply(df[-1], 1, function(x) head(sort(x, decreasing = TRUE), 3))))
```

---

A `tidyverse` option is to first `gather` the data, `arrange` it in descending order and for every row select only first three values. We then replace the `injury` column with the column names which we want and finally `spread` the data back to wide format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(injury, value, -pt_id) %>%
  arrange(desc(value)) %>%
  group_by(pt_id) %>%
  slice(1:3) %>%
  mutate(injury = 1:3) %>%
  spread(injury, value)

#  pt_id   `1`   `2`   `3`
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1     4     3     1
#2     2     5     3     3
#3     3     2     1     1
#4     4     2     1     0
#5     5     5     2     1
```

Comment: Thank you. The cbind answer was quite slow on the real dataset which is 2000 rows. However the tidyverse answer works well and is very quick. Could you clarify for me why the variable injury is used yet is not a column name. Is it just a name for the columns in the data frame?